# excel vba .Unprotect method executes but fails to unprotect sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working with an ADODB connection that reads and writes excel rows to a database.

Sporadically in using the application my worksheet enters a state where the `Worksheet.Unprotect` does not alter the sheet state.  The sheet is not protected when the workbook is opened, and nowhere in my code base is there a "protect" command.  Nevertheless, I reach a state where if I run the following macro:

```
Public Sub UnProtect()
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        exitCounter = 0
        Do While exitCounter < 50
            If ws.ProtectContents Then
                ws.UnProtect
                Debug.Print (ws.Name & " protected? " & ws.ProtectContents)
            End If
            exitCounter = exitCounter + 1
        Loop
    Next ws
End Sub
```

The output I see is the following:

```
Data protected? True
Data protected? True
Data protected? True
Data protected? True
Data protected? True
Data protected? True
Data protected? True
...
```

I don't know that there is any reproducible behavior that puts the workbook in this "broken" mode, but it happens quite frequently when using database functions.

Saving the workbook and re-opening excel resolves the issue, but it happens quite frequently and breaks the database functionality.  What VBA actions can I perform to get my model out of this state?

Comment: `UnProtect` is expecting a password, no? You haven't given it any parameters. Try `ws.Unprotect "mypassword"`.

Comment: @dwirony I don't ever knowingly protect the worksheet.  It is unprotected when the workbook opens.  Docs say the argument is optional and ignored if no password https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.unprotect

Comment: What happens when you break on `ws.Unprotect` and unprotect the sheet manually?